# Как создать ассоциативный массив в Sass в sass синтаксисе?

Tags: sass, frontend

Не получается создать ассоциативный массив в Sass используя синтаксис sass. В SCSS синтаксисе могу все сделать

```
$status-colors: (

  primary: #000,
  success: #27BA6C,
  info: #03a9f4,
  warning: #FF8833,
  danger: #ff1a1a
);
```

а вот в sass синтаксисе все перегуглил (в оф дока нет такого) и не нашел. Подскажите кто знает.

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается надо просто все писать в одну строку

```
$primary:   (success: #27BA6C, info: #03a9f4, warning: #FF8833, danger: #ff1a1a)
```

PS: долго провозился, и когда задав вопрос решение пришло само)

Comment: Если кто знает как можно не в одну строку это делать, отпишитесь

Comment: Пока никак. Предположительно в версии 3.5 появится поддержка символов перевода строк: https://github.com/sass/sass/pull/2094

Comment: Понял, спасибо за инфу